# What is amplify-backup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Working on an Amplify project, I realized that the directory contains `amplify-backup` folder. When running `amplify pull`, the command errors, pointing out the existence of `amplify-backup` and suggesting removing the folder.

I want to know how `amplify-backup` is created and the purpose of this folder.